# Django: Uppercase/Lowercase values of Django Model attributes should be treated as same

Tags: django

I have model city:

```
class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
                                message="Name should only consist of characters")
    name = models.CharField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100)
    postalcode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["state", "name"]
```

In this model name of city with all the cases (Uppercase/lowercase) should be treated as same like Udaipur/udaipur/udaiPuR all should be treated as same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your model, it should do the trick for you

```
class NameField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NameField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).lower()

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
                                message="Name should only consist of characters")
    name = NameField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100)
    postalcode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["state", "name"]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.
But I am getting error: AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'NameField'.
How to resolve this error?

Comment: I have updated my answer, now can you give it a try. Once you update this in your code make sure to perform the migrations.